# How to assign new column value based on max value in another column preceding date

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a new column called `CDAT` in the following dataframe.  With `CDAT` equal to the `"DATE"` of the last `"BRED" EVENT` from the same `ID`, `LACT` and `FDAT` combination that preceded the `"PREG" Event`

Effectively I need to groupby on `ID`, `LACT` and `FDAT` and then when there is a `"PREG" Event` fill the **New** `CDAT` column with the `"DATE"` from the most recent `"BRED" Event` that precedes the date of the `"PREG" EVENT`.

An example of the data is presented below

```
    ID  LACT    FDAT    EVENT   DATE
0   46  1   2011-09-23  BRED    2012-03-02
1   46  1   2011-09-23  PREG    2012-04-03
2   46  1   2011-09-23  PREG    2012-05-22
3   46  1   2011-09-23  PREG    2012-10-09
4   46  2   2012-11-15  FRESH   2012-11-15
5   46  2   2012-11-15  LUT     2013-01-08
6   46  2   2012-11-15  OS      2013-01-15
7   46  2   2012-11-15  BRED    2013-01-01
8   46  2   2012-11-15  BRED    2013-01-24
9   46  2   2012-11-15  PREG    2013-02-26
10  46  2   2012-11-16  BRED    2013-03-10
```

The Output I would like to achieve is

```
    ID  LACT    FDAT    EVENT   DATE         CDAT
0   46  1   2011-09-23  BRED    2012-03-02
1   46  1   2011-09-23  PREG    2012-04-03   2012-03-02
2   46  1   2011-09-23  PREG    2012-05-22   2012-03-02
3   46  1   2011-09-23  PREG    2012-10-09   2012-03-02
4   46  2   2012-11-15  FRESH   2012-11-15
5   46  2   2012-11-15  LUT     2013-01-08
6   46  2   2012-11-15  OS      2013-01-15
7   46  2   2012-11-15  BRED    2013-01-01
8   46  2   2012-11-15  BRED    2013-01-24
9   46  2   2012-11-15  PREG    2013-02-26   2013-01-24
10  46  2   2012-11-16  BRED    2013-03-10
```

I cannot think of a way to incorporate the date and EVENT selection into a groupby statement that would achieve what I would like to do.

A list of the sample data is presented below

```
[[46,1,Timestamp('2011-09-23 00:00:00'),'BRED',Timestamp('2012-03-02 00:00:00')],
 [46,1,Timestamp('2011-09-23 00:00:00'),'PREG',Timestamp('2012-04-03 00:00:00')],
 [46,1,Timestamp('2011-09-23 00:00:00'),'PREG',Timestamp('2012-05-22 00:00:00')],
 [46,1,Timestamp('2011-09-23 00:00:00'),'PREG',Timestamp('2012-10-09 00:00:00')],
 [46,2,Timestamp('2012-11-15 00:00:00'),'FRESH',Timestamp('2012-11-15 00:00:00')],
 [46,2,Timestamp('2012-11-15 00:00:00'),'LUT',Timestamp('2013-01-08 00:00:00')],
 [46,2,Timestamp('2012-11-15 00:00:00'),'OS',Timestamp('2013-01-15 00:00:00')],
 [46,2,Timestamp('2012-11-15 00:00:00'),'BRED',Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00')],
 [46,2,Timestamp('2012-11-15 00:00:00'),'BRED',Timestamp('2013-01-24 00:00:00')],
 [46,2,Timestamp('2012-11-15 00:00:00'),'PREG',Timestamp('2013-02-26 00:00:00')],
 [46,2,Timestamp('2012-11-16 00:00:00'),'BRED',Timestamp('2013-03-10 00:00:00')],
 [46,2,Timestamp('2012-11-15 00:00:00'),'PREG',Timestamp('2013-04-16 00:00:00')],
 [46,2,Timestamp('2001-11-15 00:00:00'),'PREG',Timestamp('2013-08-06 00:00:00')]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[46,1,pd.Timestamp('2011-09-23'),'BRED',pd.Timestamp('2012-03-02')],
                     [46,1,pd.Timestamp('2011-09-23'),'PREG',pd.Timestamp('2012-04-03')],
                     [46,1,pd.Timestamp('2011-09-23'),'PREG',pd.Timestamp('2012-05-22')],
                     [46,1,pd.Timestamp('2011-09-23'),'PREG',pd.Timestamp('2012-10-09')],
                     [46,2,pd.Timestamp('2012-11-15'),'FRESH',pd.Timestamp('2012-11-15')],
                     [46,2,pd.Timestamp('2012-11-15'),'LUT',pd.Timestamp('2013-01-08')],
                     [46,2,pd.Timestamp('2012-11-15'),'OS',pd.Timestamp('2013-01-15')],
                     [46,2,pd.Timestamp('2012-11-15'),'BRED',pd.Timestamp('2013-01-01')],
                     [46,2,pd.Timestamp('2012-11-15'),'BRED',pd.Timestamp('2013-01-24')],
                     [46,2,pd.Timestamp('2012-11-15'),'PREG',pd.Timestamp('2013-02-26')],
                     [46,2,pd.Timestamp('2012-11-16'),'BRED',pd.Timestamp('2013-03-10')]],
                    columns=['ID', 'LACT', 'FDAT', 'EVENT', 'DATE'])

df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'LACT', 'FDAT', 'DATE'])

last_bred_dates = []
for name, group in df.groupby(['ID', 'LACT', 'FDAT']):
    last_bred_date = np.nan
    for i, row in group.iterrows():
        if row['EVENT'] == 'BRED':
            last_bred_date = row['DATE']
            last_bred_dates.append(np.nan)
        elif row['EVENT'] == 'PREG':
            last_bred_dates.append(last_bred_date)
        else:
            last_bred_dates.append(np.nan)
        
df['CDAT'] = pd.Series(last_bred_dates)
```

Output:

|  | ID | LACT | FDAT | EVENT | DATE | CDAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 46 | 1 | 2011-09-23 00:00:00 | BRED | 2012-03-02 00:00:00 | NaT |
| 1 | 46 | 1 | 2011-09-23 00:00:00 | PREG | 2012-04-03 00:00:00 | 2012-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 46 | 1 | 2011-09-23 00:00:00 | PREG | 2012-05-22 00:00:00 | 2012-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 46 | 1 | 2011-09-23 00:00:00 | PREG | 2012-10-09 00:00:00 | 2012-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 46 | 2 | 2012-11-15 00:00:00 | FRESH | 2012-11-15 00:00:00 | NaT |
| 7 | 46 | 2 | 2012-11-15 00:00:00 | BRED | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 | NaT |
| 5 | 46 | 2 | 2012-11-15 00:00:00 | LUT | 2013-01-08 00:00:00 | NaT |
| 6 | 46 | 2 | 2012-11-15 00:00:00 | OS | 2013-01-15 00:00:00 | NaT |
| 8 | 46 | 2 | 2012-11-15 00:00:00 | BRED | 2013-01-24 00:00:00 | NaT |
| 9 | 46 | 2 | 2012-11-15 00:00:00 | PREG | 2013-02-26 00:00:00 | 2013-01-24 00:00:00 |
| 10 | 46 | 2 | 2012-11-16 00:00:00 | BRED | 2013-03-10 00:00:00 | NaT |

**Explanation**:

Group the df based on `['ID', 'LACT', 'FDAT']` to get the desired groups. Then create an empty list and iterate on that groups, if the `EVENT`of that row is a `BRED Event` save the `DATE` value and append a NaN to the list, if the `EVENT`of that row is a `PREG Event` append the saved value to the list, with any other event append a NaN to the list. Finally use that list to create the new `CDAT` column.
Note that before iterating on each group the variable `last_bred_date` is assigned with a NaN in order to append to the list only the dates of that group.